# Is it possible to pass a dynamic group value to tokenizer in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I want to specify the grouping size dynamically.

Is something like this possible ?

```
split().tokenize("\n", ..value from header or property...)
```

how to specify this value ?

--Clarifying: my question reads like I intend to dynamically change it during the execution of the route. 
This is not what I need,

I need just a way to pass in a configurable splitsize, that is calculated in a bean.

Comment: You can do this in a processor using mixture of java streams and camel to split based on dynamic size.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible, the group is a fixed number.

However instead of using tokenize you can use a java method call and return an `Expression` where you can do something similar to what `TokenizeLanguage#createExpression` does but where you can set the group value with a dynamic value.

Comment: I am calculating the split size prior to coming into the route that does the split. Even in the case is it not possible ?

Comment: No its not possible the size is fixed

Comment: I logged a ticket to add dynamic group to a future release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11421